# css formatting of jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a web-based utility for chess tournament manual pairings. I need to format jquery ui autocomplete to make the white players select menu items left justified and the black players select menu items right justified. Here is the link: http://communitychessclub.com/test.php

I have seen many confusing and probably contradictory CSS styling methods. For example:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu {background:pink; font-size:1.5rem; text-align:center; letter-spacing:2px;}  

.ui-widget-content.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
.ui-widget-content.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {color: tan; font-weight: bold;}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class = "ui-widget white"><input type = "text" class = "automplete-2"></div>
<div class = "ui-widget black"><input type = "text" class = "automplete-2"></div><br />
```

How can I have the white player's autocomplete listing left-justified and the black player's autocomplete listing right-justified.

Comment: I need text-align:left for black players and text-align:right for the white players

Comment: Looks ok on your test page, unless you want to swap white and black justification, then just switch text-alight: left; with text-align: right;

Comment: Not at all... I am using jquery autocomplete... and I want *that* list to be alternately right / left justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the even / odd argument of [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector:

```
.ui-menu:nth-of-type(even) li div{  /* black */
  text-align: left !important;
}
.ui-menu:nth-of-type(odd) li div{  /* white */
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited... Since there is some `div` in between... There were all `even` using `nth-child(even/odd)`... So I found `nth-of-type` is working. ;)